# What happens when script execution finishes ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Learning ajax at the moment and was wondering what would happen if:

You let the script execution continue whilst the ajax is processed:

```
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "php_script.php", true);
```

What happens if the script execution finishes before the server returns the results from php_script.php?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume for context that the script is running as part of a web page in the browser.  You want to set the "onreadystatechange" property of the request to a handler function.  When the result comes in, the handler will be called even if the main script has returned to idle.

In some sense, event driven scripts don't actually end - they just go idle waiting for more events.